# OpenSSL Java security provider

Tags: java, security, applet, openssl, client-certificates

I have to connect from java applet to soap webservice with two-way ssl authentication, i.e. using client certificate. Also, i **have to use openssl**.

I'm trying to use that code (source - https://sites.google.com/site/ssljavaguide/example-code/2-way-ssl):

```
try{
    // necessary keystore properties - using a p12 file
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","client_keystore.p12");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","01234543210");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");

    //set necessary truststore properties - using JKS
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","truststoreCA.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","pleas3w0rk");
    // register a https protocol handler  - this may be required for previous JDK versions
    System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs","com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");

    //connect to google   
    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket sslSock = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("mail.google.com",443);

    //send HTTP get request
    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sslSock.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
    wr.write("GET /mail HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: mail.google.com\r\n\r\n");
    wr.flush();

    // read response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslSock.getInputStream()));
    String string = null;

    while ((string = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(string);
        System.out.flush();
    }

    rd.close();
    wr.close();

    // Close connection.
    sslSock.close();

}
catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Is there `java.security.Provider` implementation, that use openssl library and i can put in the function `Security.addProvider()`?

Comment: Why do you think you have to use OpenSSL? Java's JSSE can talk to OpenSSL without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to get algorithms from openssl? Java Security class don't see some of them.

Comment: @SomeUser instead of requirement to use OpenSSL, post requirement to use those algorithms, otherwise, your point is unclear.

Comment: I need to use GOST algorithms. BUT, i have to use OpenSSL, not some other implementations.

Comment: Please answer my question. Just repeating the requirement does not constitute an answer.

Comment: I need to use OpenSSL because some version of this program is certified  (http://www.cryptocom.ru/products/cryptopacket.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try use JuiCE (http://incubator.apache.org/projects/juice.html) its a JCE provider that makes use of OpenSSL. But the project retired on 2007-10-18 due to lack of community interest.